# The Blackguards' powers in Wolverine: Weapon X?

Tags: comics, marvel, wolverine

In Wolverine: Weapon X, Wolverine encounters a set of humans "improved" by nanites that given them a lot of the powers that Wolverine himself has, including improved healing and claws.  I ended up with two questions about their powers:

- All their eyes glow green, and I was wondering whether this was a power of some kind.
- Their claws also glow green, but that's stated that they are "lasers".  Why do their claws terminate if they are lasers?

Their laser claws are mentioned and green eyes shown in the below panels (apologies for the low resolution):

[image]

Their claws are shown on this cover:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Blackguard or Strikeforce X are an attempt to create human soldiers with the physical capabilities of Wolverine, using technology to replicate to varying degrees Wolverine's physical capabilities. They have adamantium-laced skeletons from the Weapon X project and they appear to have substituted enhanced sight instead of olifactory senses. They also appear to have skimped on the adamantium-claw upgrade, substituting a metallic/laser-enhanced hybrid. (As you suggested, lasers don't terminate.)**

The Blackguard are non-mutant humans who have been technologically enhanced using drugs, techno-organic nanites (for an enhanced healing factor to counter the adamantium-process used to give them damage-resistance) and other bionic implants (energy claws and possibly eyes).

Likely it was easier to give them enhanced visual capacity than olifactory senses. So I suspect they have the same capacity as cats for absorbing and capturing more light from their surroundings. These would be the equivalent of [starlight lenses](http://www.optics4birding.com/starlight-technology.aspx), something these soldiers would be familiar with, requiring less training.

As far as their claws, they are not lasers but a high grade metal enhanced with some sort of laser system to improve their cutting and damage dealing capacity. The glowing eyes and claws are also likely invoking the TVtropes concept [The Rule of Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool). Fans were quite taken with the glowing claws. Though I question why they didn't just get the full adamantium upgrade? Cost limitation? Unavailability of secondary adamantium?

They are also highly skilled with various firearms and often use specialized ammunition.

Comment: On the claws, the Blackguard say they're using "laser claws" without mentioning the underlying metal.  The metal makes more sense, but where was the metal part mentioned?

Comment: It's not. It has to be inferred. Most people don't have enough of a scientific background to know that lasers don't terminate in mid-air. They are thinking "light-sabers in claw form; COOL." I long for a world where people know enough science that when you break the rules, we can just accept it but know that its for the sake of cool and not physically possible.